# Struggling to set a PHP variable within a Postgresql SELECT statement

Tags: php, postgresql, get

This is how I currently have it set up. I want to grab the users input and store that into a variable and then store a select statement in a variable and call it into the API GET call combined as one.

```
$deviceid= $_POST['deviceid'];
$query= "SELECT * FROM view_device_v1 WHERE view_device_v1.device_pk = '".$deviceid."'";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com//services/data/v1.0/query/? "'.$query."'",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
```

Here is my HTML code below as well for a reference.

```
  <fieldset>
  <legend> Search by ID</legend>
  <form method="GET" action="search_device42ID.php">
  <input type="text" name="deviceid" value="">
  <input class="button-device42" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" class ="mybutton" value="Device42 Search">
  </form>
  </fieldset>

<br>
<br>
```

Comment: 1) `method="GET"` and `$_POST` is not going to work. 2) Your query param is missing a key / name. Usually they look like `?key=value`. You will also need to encode the `$query` variable into the URL via [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the form method in your HTML code set to "GET", but your PHP code is using "POST".

To fix this, if the data being sent does not need to be sent securely, change your PHP code to:

```
$deviceid = $_GET['deviceid'];
```

Or if the data being sent does need to be sent securely, change your HTML form code to:

```
<form method="POST" action="search_device42ID.php">
```